# Android workmanage is not being restarted after connection lost

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I created a CoroutineWorker to download a video file in the background. It works until my phone gets airplane mode. By enabling airplane mode I simulate connection loss. I expect that work will be retried after the connection will be restored but nothing happens.

```
   val data = Data.Builder()
    data.apply {
        putString(VideoDownloadWorker.EXTRA_LINK_TO_FILE, info.link)
        putLong(VideoDownloadWorker.EXTRA_USER_ID, info.userId)
        putString(VideoDownloadWorker.EXTRA_VIDEO_SLUG, info.videoSlug)
        putString(VideoDownloadWorker.EXTRA_LINK_PREVIEW, info.preview)
        putString(VideoDownloadWorker.EXTRA_VIDEO_NAME, info.videoName)
    }
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .setRequiresStorageNotLow(true)
        .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
        .build()
    val downloadWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<VideoDownloadWorker>()
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInputData(data.build())
        .build()
    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext())
    val workUniqueName = "VideoDownload_${info.videoSlug}"

    workManager.beginUniqueWork(
        workUniqueName,
        ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        downloadWork
    ).enqueue()
```

I read that the work manager has to retry by itself but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found out how to retry the work. Added try/catch block to my worker where placed downloading logic and return Result.retry().

```
        val videoPath = try {
        downloadAndSaveVideo(
            link = link,
            saveDirection = videoDir.path,
            videoName = videoSlug
        ) { progress ->
            if (progress > currentProgress) {
                currentProgress = progress
                updateProgress(currentProgress)
            }
            Log.d("DOWNLOAD PROGRESS", progress.toString())
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        return Result.retry()
    }
```